# Invalid Route Action When Routing invokable class

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-9

iam new in laravel , and i wrote this code at routes/api.php in laravel 9

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth',
    'namespace' => 'Auth'
], function(){
    Route::post('register', 'RegisterController');
});
```

and then i got cant run php artisan serve , it said

```
 UnexpectedValueException 

  Invalid route action: [Auth\RegisterController].

  at G:\PRODUCTIVITY\SANBERCODE\LARAVEL-VUE\TUGAS\laravel-vue-crowdfunding-website-batch-37\crowdfunding-website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction.php:92
     88▕      */
     89▕     protected static function makeInvokable($action)
     90▕     {
     91▕         if (! method_exists($action, '__invoke')) {
  ➜  92▕             throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid route action: [{$action}].");
     93▕         }
     94▕
     95▕         return $action.'@__invoke';
     96▕     }

  1   G:\PRODUCTIVITY\SANBERCODE\LARAVEL-VUE\TUGAS\laravel-vue-crowdfunding-website-batch-37\crowdfunding-website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction.php:47
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction::makeInvokable("Auth\RegisterController")

  2   G:\PRODUCTIVITY\SANBERCODE\LARAVEL-VUE\TUGAS\laravel-vue-crowdfunding-website-batch-37\crowdfunding-website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:190
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction::parse("api/auth/register", ["Auth\RegisterController", "Auth\RegisterController"])
```

someone please help me :)

Comment: why it can be error like that , and how to fix it ?

Comment: Attach your RegisterController code

Comment: You have to either give us RegisterController code or to tell us is that controller invokable or not? Invokable controller must have '__invoke()' function, if you don't know what is Invokable controller then you are definitely not using it. But still give us or code or check my answer below!

Answer (score -1):

Add RegisterController function

```
     Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth',
    'namespace' => 'Auth'
], function(){
    Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@store');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a parameter in your `post` function from `Route`.

You want something like

```
Route::post('route_name', 'Controller@myFunction')
```

Or in your case:

```
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@registerFunctionName');
```

Other variation per 9.x documentation:

```
Route::post('register',  [RegisterController::class, 'registerFunctionName']);
```

Please refer to:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing

Answer (score -2):

This is an invokable controller yes?

you need to just alter the syntax

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth',
    'namespace' => 'Auth'
], function(){
    Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class]);
});
```

and then import the class at the top of your routes file and make sure you have a single public method of `__invoke()` in your controller.